# A template function as a template argument

Tags: c++, c++20

How to make the pseudo code below compile?

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void CopyVector() { std::vector<T> v; /*...*/}

template <class T>
void CopyVectorAsync() { std::vector<T> v; /*...*/}

template <template <class> void copy()>
void Test()
{
    copy<char>();
    copy<short>();
    copy<int>();
}

int main()
{
    Test<CopyVector>();
    Test<CopyVectorAsync>();
}
```

`CopyVector` and `CopyVectorAsync` are the functions that copy some vector of elements of type `T` using different algorithms. `Test` function calls a given copy functions with different element types. `main` function calls `CopyVector` and `CopyVectorAsync` for all the element types.

Comment: `CopyVector` and `CopyVectorAsync` aren't functions, they are function templates. It's not a pedantic distinction, but an important one for those who wish to reason about the type system without getting confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a template template parameter that accepts function templates, only class templates. Luckily we can make a class that looks rather like a function.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct CopyVector { void operator()() { std::vector<T> v; /*...*/} };

template <class T>
struct CopyVectorAsync{ void operator()() { std::vector<T> v; /*...*/} };

template <template <class> class copy>
void Test()
{
    copy<char>{}();
    copy<short>{}();
    copy<int>{}();
}

int main()
{
    Test<CopyVector>();
    Test<CopyVectorAsync>();
}
```

Comment: _You can't have a template template parameter for function templates, only for class templates._ To me this seems to mean that I can't have `template<template<typename> typename T> void f(T<int>)`.Is the wording confusing just for me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass overload set or functions template as (template) parameter.

You can pass template template parameter for classes:

```
template <template <class> class copy>
void Test()
{
    copy<char>{}();
    copy<short>{}();
    copy<int>{}();
}

template <class T>
struct CopyVector
{
    void operator()() const{ /*...*/}
};

int main()
{
    Test<CopyVector>();
}
```

or pass functor with template method.

```
template <typename copy>
void Test()
{
    copy{}.template operator()<char>();
    copy{}.template operator()<short>();
    copy{}.template operator()<int>();
}

template <class T>
void CopyVector() { /*...*/}

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []<typename T>(){ CopyVector<T>(); };
    Test<decltype(lambda)>();
}
```

Passing parameter by regular argument might allow "simpler" syntax:

```
template <typename T>
void Test(T f)
{
    f(std::type_identity<char>{});
    f(std::type_identity<short>{});
    f(std::type_identity<int>{});
}

template <class T>
void CopyVector(std::type_identity<T>) { /*...*/}

int main()
{
    Test([]<typename T>(std::type_identity<T>){ CopyVector<T>(); });
}
```